# How can I stop a Perl subroutine if it takes too long?

Tags: perl, subroutine

I created a subroutine `sub_info` in Perl. So in my Perl script, it reads each line of input file and call sub_info subroutine. However, for some of the input lines, sub_info takes very long time to run. So basically I want to calculate the running time of sub_info subroutine for each of input line and if it takes more than 15 minutes, I want to pass that input line and run `sub_info` subroutine for next input line. Is there any function to calculate time for running a subroutine in Perl?

Comment: Vote to reopen. This is not a question about profiling.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably go with some combination of `SIG{ALRM}` and [`alarm`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

$|=1;

for my $i (1 .. 10) {

  local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
    die;
  };

  eval {
    alarm 5;
    sub_info($i);
  };

  if ($@) {
    print "aborted\n";
  }
  alarm 0;
}

sub sub_info {
  my $i = shift;
  my $r = int(10*rand);

  printf "Trying %2d for %2d seconds: ", $i, $r;
  sleep $r;
  print "finished\n";
}
```

With `alarm n` you specify that after `n` seconds a SIGALRM signal is delivered to the calling process. When the processes receives such a signal, it does what is specified in `$SIG{ALRM}`. In the sample script above it just dies.

So, if a `sub_info` call takes less than 5 seconds, `die` is not invoked, yet if it takes more, the `die` is invoked.

You don't want the entire process to die, so you wrap the call to `sub_info` into an `eval` block. If the eval block has died, `$@` will be set. So you check for a true value in `$@` in which case you know that 5 seconds were exceeded.